# OO Selenium test cases?

Tags: oop, selenium

Is it possible to import scripts to a selenium test case, when using the selenium IDE. For example all of my test cases will require a login. However I do not want to login on every test case. I would rather write one test case that is concerned with logging in and then import this into all of the other test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group you cases in a test suite and place your login case as the first one in that suite.

Comment: So I am assuming that Selenium uses the same session for all of its test cases.?
However this would not help if I was working on a single test case and wanted to test and modify, as I would have to run all of the test cases. I guess I could have a test suite for each test I want and then include all test cases prior to it; however this would mean I would have to open multiple test suites if I wanted to export them to Java to later use on a nightly build which is our long term goal.

Comment: You can have only one test suite and if you need to modify a single test ant "debug" it afterwards you can select (Ctrl+Click) just that test and the login test.

Answer (score 0):

You could also load a external file with functions (e.g. login) in all test cases. Then you can run the login/logout function in every testcase.

```
include 'Testing/functions.php';
login($this);
.
.
.
logout($this);
```